# Displaying ProgressBar in Activity of TabHost

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout

I am using TabHost in my application. When I use ProgressBar in any one of the activity the application stops unexpectedly.

When any Tab is clicked, the corresponding activity is called. This activity does some background processing(gets data from WebService) and then displays that data. The problem is when I use ProgressBar its not working. The application gets forcefully closed. 
I want to display ProgressBar till the activity gets the data from the WebService.

Comment: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(477): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 19:17:38.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(477):

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.com.home/my.com.home.HomeActivity}:

android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token

android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@4051fef0 is not valid; is your activity running?
03-08 19:17:38.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(477):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1622)
03-08 19:17:38.933:

Comment: It throws many RunTime exceptions

Comment: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(477):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1622)
03-08 19:17:38.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(477):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
03-08 19:17:38.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(477):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-08 19:17:38.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(477):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
03-08 19:17:38.933: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(477):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

Comment: Use ProgressDialog.show(getParent(),"My Msg");  GetParent will help you dude... try and say wt happen?

Comment: @Ganapathy : Yeah, the problem is solved using this....thanks alot....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
ProgressDialog.show(getParent(),"My Msg");
```

GetParent will help you.

Thank you.

Comment: That's the answer, you can cast your context to activity and use get parent method like this:Activity act=(Activity)context;ProgressDialog.show(act.getParent(),"My Msg");